# Retrieve an Email from Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Is there anyone who could tell me how to retrieve an Email from Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Assume that the Marketing Cloud Connector is already OK.

Comment: If you'd like the community to help you out, you're going to have to supply more details.  What have you tried? Any code you can post?

Comment: Thx Adam! I had already got the answer by seached the soap api and asked my mate.

Comment: Care to share a generic version of your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the soap api of Marketing Cloud to fetched emails of MC, and the following is my solution:

```
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
    req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'Retrieve');


    String eBody = '';
    eBody += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
    eBody += '<soapenv:Header>';
    eBody += '<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">';
    eBody += '<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">';
    eBody += '<wsse:Username>SFMC Connector API User</wsse:Username>';
    eBody += '<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">yourpassword</wsse:Password>';
    eBody += '</wsse:UsernameToken>';
    eBody += '</wsse:Security>';
    eBody += '</soapenv:Header>';
    eBody += '<soapenv:Body>';
    eBody += '<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">';
    eBody += '<RetrieveRequest>';
    eBody += '<ObjectType>Email</ObjectType>';
    eBody += '<Properties>ID</Properties>';
    eBody += '<Properties>Name</Properties>';
    eBody += '<Properties>Subject</Properties>';
    eBody += '<Properties>ContentAreas</Properties>';
    eBody += '<Properties>HTMLBody</Properties>';

    // If need a filter
        eBody += '<Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">';
        eBody += '<Property>ID</Property>';
        eBody += '<SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>';
        eBody += '<Value>12345</Value>';
        eBody += '</Filter>';


    eBody += '</RetrieveRequest>';
    eBody += '</RetrieveRequestMsg>';
    eBody += '</soapenv:Body>';
    eBody += '</soapenv:Envelope>';

    req.setBody(eBody);
    req.setTimeout(120000);
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

    System.debug('qqqq res.getBody=' + res.getBody());
```

Hope this can help someone!